# Proving increasing function using expectation

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

Given $c>0$ and define a function $f:(0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}
f(\sigma)=\frac1{\sqrt {2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\max\{-c,\min\{x,c\}\}^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}.
\end{equation}
We can see $f$ as the second moment of $X_c=\max\{-c,\min\{X,c\}\}$ where $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. I could prove that $f$ is increasing using derivative which is very tedious. I'd like to see $f$ is increasing using expectation approach. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the random variable $X$ have *any* distribution $F$. We can remove the infinite endpoints in the integral, showing there are no worries about whether moments of $F$ exist:

$$\eqalign{
e(F,c) &= \mathbb{E}_F\left(\max\{-c, \min\{X,c\}\}^2\right) \\
&=\mathbb{E}_F\left(c^2 + (X^2 - c^2) I_{|X|\le c}\right) \\
&=c^2 - \mathbb{E}_F\left((c^2 - X^2) I_{|X|\le c}\right).
}$$

(The notation "$I_{|X| \le c}$" is the indicator function for the set $|X| \le c$, equal to $1$ on the set and $0$ elsewhere.)

Now rescale $X$ by $\sigma \gt 0$; that is, suppose that $Y = X/\sigma$ has the distribution $F$, and consider the right hand term:

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_F\left(\left(c^2 - \left(\sigma Y\right)^2 \right) I_{|\sigma Y |\le c}\right).
}$$

Because this expectation occurs with a negative sign in $e(F,c),$ it follows that $e(F,c)$ decreases as $X$ is rescaled by ever larger values of $\sigma.$

The function inside the expectation is non-negative: it is the part of a parabola rising above the axis.  Its apex is always at height $c$ when $Y=0$, but *it is being horizontally shrunk by a factor of $\sigma$*.

[image: Figure: three parabolae]

*As $\sigma$ increases (values of $\sigma=1/2, 1, 2$ are shown here), the parabola shrinks.  The expectations are the probability-weighted integrals of these functions.  The question asks to show that these expectations decrease as the parabola shrinks.*

We can easily show this algebraically (but without the same geometric insight) by noting that whenever $\sigma^\prime \gt \sigma,$

$$c^2 - \left(\sigma Y\right)^2 \gt c^2 - \left(\sigma^\prime Y\right)^2.$$

Consequently, because $I_{|\sigma Y |\le c} \ge I_{|\sigma^\prime Y |\le c}$, the expression inside the expectation is non-decreasing (and is strictly decreasing whenever $|Y| \lt c/\sigma$).  Therefore the expectation itself cannot increase and in fact must decrease whenever $F$ assigns positive probability to the interval $(-c/\sigma, c/\sigma)$.

The setting of the question is the case where $F$ is a standard normal distribution.  Because it assigns positive probability density to all numbers, *a fortiori* it assigns positive probabilities to all intervals $(-c/\sigma, c/\sigma),$ whence the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for your help @whuber.